# Criticism of Paper

Tags: research-process, databases

This is my first exercise which involves reading a paper and finding shortcomings or gaps in it.

This is towards a database course for my masters degree. My paper deals with validation of xml using DTD specification. There are lot of proofs in the paper using automata theory.

I would like to know how to identify the gaps or the missing points in the technique so that I am in a position to construct a criticism of this paper. This course is for 20 credits, so I am trying to put lot of efforts in it.

Just some general help will be fine, I am not looking for specific answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Work through the proofs, make sure definitions are given (and agree with standard sources, as applicable) and are used consistently. Are the definitions really required later? Does it refer/use related work?

When trying to check (or understand, more or less the same thing, you need to be *convinced* beyond reasonable doubt) a proof, you think on how it could fail. I.e., look for corner cases, check some simple cases to see how it could go wrong. Check each step of the proof in the above way. See if you can come up with an alternative proof (simpler, using different techniques).

See if the different proofs hang well together. Look for possible extensions, other areas where the proof technique might be applied.

Check for overall coherence: does the abstract tell the right story, are the conclusions/summary really warranted.